# Disable chatter notifications at profile level

Tags: chatter

We have an API user and want to disable chatter notifications for that profile. Is that at all possible?

Comment: this link may help you:    https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176019&language=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always disable chatter notification from user profile.

1. Login to that user.
2. Click your name from top left
3. visit my settings page

[image]

4. Disable the notification as shown below

[image]

[Salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176019&language=en_US)